# How to diagnose an unexpected delay during dragging?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, debugging, instruments

From time to time, one of my apps experiences a delay of 2-10sec whilst dragging an object in a complex view. In some cases, the delay is sufficient to cause the wait cursor (spinning pizza of death) to appear.

Time Profiler reveals nothing very remarkable -- just the expected drawing calls to update the view as the object is dragged. (This is a lot of computation, but I see no obvious difference in the profile during pauses and between pauses.)

Memory profiler reveals nothing special about the pauses. Allocation seems flat throughout the drag. Leaks is clean.  (My initial assumption was that I was spinning off too many autoreleased objects, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.)

Activity Monitor indicates that during the drag I'm pretty much using up one core for all the redrawing. That's what I expect.

Any ideas of where to look next?

Comment: Any chance any code paths touch the disk?

Comment: Or if your memory usage is high, some of the application memory could have been swapped out to disk, then it would take a little while to access it again...

Comment: The pauses run from 2 to 10 seconds -- I think that's really too long for even a big VM hit. Activity Monitor doesn't show any disk usage spikes.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Well maybe you could try running Instruments.app with 'Record Waiting Threads' enabled. This will show you where the code is waiting as well as running. You might be sitting in a semaphore or doing some IO- that will show up in this mode.

[image: Instruments]